# what is the right way to use the new "--freeze" option in startmigration for django-south?

Tags: django, migration

I've tried the following but this seems to only create an empty migration file:

```
startmigration appname freeze_appname --freeze appname
```

i've also tried just:

```
startmigration --freeze appname
```

doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok since i see no SOUTH users around, i had to figure out how to do this.

what i did wrong was create the data migrations first without freezing the apps

i did this:

```
startmigration appname migrate_data
```

and this created the blank migrations file where i then put in my data migration functions. but i did not freeze the apps i wanted to use/access withing the migration

the right way to do this would have been:

```
startmigration appname migrate_data --freeze apptouseinmigration
```